# How do I redirect the java logger output MQTT to a topic on a specific MQTT broker

Tags: java, logging, mqtt, iot

I have a java program collecting energy data on an IOT device which it sends over MQTT to Node-RED for storage on InFlux and presentation via Grafana. I also send simple log messages over MQTT on a separate topic to Node-RED for debugging purposes. I can get the console on my IOT device (an RPi Zero W) via SSH but it is very slow and unreliable. I would like to use the java system logger for logging, but I want the output formatted as a readable string or json and sent to a topic I specify on my MQTT broker.
So is there a logging handler available to do this or how would I go about writing one?

My current logger is shown below, and picks up log messages from a shared queue of strings

```
public class PMLogger extends Thread
{
    String msg;
    LinkedBlockingQueue<String> loggingQ;

    public PMLogger(LinkedBlockingQueue<String> logQ)
    {
        this.loggingQ = logQ;
    }

    //
    // Runnable implementation
    //
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); // wait for publisher to be set up
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        MQTTHandler publisher = Main.getMqttHandler();
        String json;
        boolean exit = false;
        try {
            while (!(interrupted() || exit)) {
                msg = loggingQ.take();
                if (msg.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                    exit = true;
                } //poison pill
                json = "{\"Time\":" +
                        "\"" + Instant.now().toString() + "\"," +
                        "\"LogMsg\":" +
                        "\"" + msg + "\"}";
                publisher.logToBroker(json);
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            exit = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I found [loggly.com](https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/java-logging-basics/) useful in explaining the terminology, having read through that, I believe I am looking for an appender that works with MQTT

Comment: I see log4j to mqtt appender on github: https://github.com/radekg/log4mqtt
(I did not try it)

Comment: I had a quick look at this, but it is not maintained and not current. I was hoping to use the front end of the standard logger, but redirect the back end with an MQQT handler, so this was in the right ball park, thanks

Answer (score 0):

[SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) is a good choice for anything java logging related, no need to reinvent the wheel. You can log in any file format you want.

Comment: I don't want it in a file I want to send over MQTT

Comment: Ok, you can do that with SLF4J still

Comment: OK having read through the introduction to SLF4J, it seems to be positioned as a framework to front other logging systems (although it does have the components to make an independent logging system). I don't need the isolation layer it provides, just a new appender.